# eclipse glassfish 3 , client error

Tags: java, glassfish-3

I am using latest Eclipse to develop EJB 3 under Glassfish 3. I create a new Glassfish server instance in the Eclipse, write a simple EJB, deployed and succeeded.

Now I write a client, but it always give me error like this

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:148)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:372)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:402)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:347)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.client.Test.main(Test.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:120)
    ... 8 more
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'helloRemote' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr]]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.client.Test.main(Test.java:22)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:504)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:148)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getORB(SerialContext.java:365)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProviderCacheKey(SerialContext.java:372)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getRemoteProvider(SerialContext.java:402)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getProvider(SerialContext.java:347)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:120)
    ... 8 more
```

the client code is this

```
Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial",  "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",  "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");


         InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);

         HelloRemote remote = (HelloRemote) ic.lookup("helloRemote");
         System.out.println(remote.echo("john"));
```

Do you know why ? is it "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory" not in the classpath ?

The source code is here
http://www.mediafire.com/file/278rc1tpip0rjku/EJBApp2.rar

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Someone else had what could easily be the same problem at http://forums.java.net/node/794493 they got it working

Comment: doesn't work for my case. same error

Comment: See Step 3 of the [EJB FAQ](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB): You need `gf-client.jar` in your `CLASSPATH`.

Answer (score 12):

To solve this issue, you just need to add external jar "appserv-rt.jar" in the buildpath of the client.

You can find it in the folder ...\glassfishv3\glassfish\lib

Or create a package with this jar and all its dependencies to add it in the BP

This is my code

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
HelloWorld helloWorldRemote = (HelloWorld) ctx.lookup("ejb/helloWorldBeanJndiName");
System.out.println(helloWorldRemote.sayHello());
```

Without the jar file, i got the same error and with I get "Hello" in the console.

Comment: The library appserv-rt.jar solved my "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr" problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the properties you set this must be a standalone client.

Make sure you include the gf-client.jar to your classpath for this to work. (glassfish\lib\gf-client.jar)

You also don't need to set the properties you set. To specify a non-localhost location of your server or alternative port however you might set:

```
prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
prop.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
```

You also might want to go over "How do I access a Remote EJB component from a stand-alone java client?" at:
http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#StandaloneRemoteEJB

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your trying to establish a connection from an application that is not deployed on your server which handles the connnectionpool

Answer (score -1):

I had similar error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Orb initialization erorr at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:180)
```

which was caused by

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.glassfish.enterprise.iiop.api.GlassFishORBHelper.getORB(GlassFishORBHelper.java:152)
```

My solution was to add jar that contains GlassFishORBFactoryImpl.class that implements the GlassFishORBHelper interface.